# Confusion about the application of the definition of size $\alpha$ test to define the rejection region in a hypothesis test exercise

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, inference

**Definition of level or size of a test**

A test is said to be of level or size $\alpha $ if

$\sup _{\theta \in \Theta_0} \beta(\theta)\le \alpha$

where $\beta$ is the power function

**Exercise**

**We want to test the hypothesis  $H_0: \lambda = 65$ where $\lambda$ is the parameter of a Poisson, against the Hypothesis $H_1: \lambda\neq 65, \alpha = 0.02$. Find the rejection region using as statistics $\bar X$, for n=10 samples. Assume to split $\alpha$ in equal parts between the right and left tail.**

Since $n\bar X \sim P(n\lambda)$, under $H_0$ we have that $Z=10\bar X \sim P(650)$
The form of $H_1$ suggests that the rejection region has the form $R=\{\underline X: \bar X\le \gamma_1 
 \cup \bar X\ge \gamma_2\}=\{\underline X: Z\le n\gamma_1:=\gamma_1 ^* \cup Z\ge n\gamma_2:=\gamma_2 ^*\}$

Since we want $\alpha =0.02$, it follows that  we need to find $\gamma_1 ^*$ and $\gamma_2 ^*$ such that

$\gamma_1 ^*=\max\{\gamma \in \mathbb{R^+}: \mathbb{P}(Z\le\gamma|H_0$ is true$)\le 0.01$ $\}$  and

$\gamma_2 ^*=\min\{\gamma \in \mathbb{R^+}: \mathbb{P}(Z\ge\gamma|H_0$ is true$)\le 0.01$ $\}$

Using ppois and qpois R functions we can find $\gamma_1 ^*=590$ and $\gamma_1 ^*=711$

**I am confused about why I need to take the max and min.**
I would write just that

$\mathbb{P}(Z\le\gamma|H_0$ is true$)$$\le \alpha/2=0.001$  and

$\mathbb{P}(Z\ge\gamma|H_0$ is true$)$$\le \alpha/2=0.001$

need to be satisfied and that would agree with the definition of $\alpha$ given above, and for that I could take any  $\gamma \le \max\{\gamma \in \mathbb{R^+}: \mathbb{P}(Z\le\gamma|H_0$ is true$)\le 0.01$ $\}$ as $\gamma_1 ^*$ and any  $\gamma \ge \min\{\gamma \in \mathbb{R^+}: \mathbb{P}(Z\ge\gamma|H_0$ is true$)$ $\le 0.01\}$ as $\gamma_2 ^*$. I understand that in the discrete case the $=$ is not always possible, but in the given solution I don't see any mathematical reason to take the max  an min and the definition does not say the probability has to be as close as possible to $\alpha$.

**Can someone clear this up?**

Comment: What is your understanding of "sup" in the definition?

Comment: @whuber the sup in this case is not there since $\Theta_0$ is just $\lambda=65$.

Comment: In a general setting the sup is least upper bound of the power function

Comment: Okay, now connect that to max and min (with suitable allowance for some possible sloppiness in using those terms in place of sup and inf).

Comment: @whuber I don't know how to do that and how that leads to conclude that  for instance $\gamma_1^ *$must be the max